# Prove series task

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If $a_n > 0$, $a_{n+1} \le a_n$ for all $n \in N$ and $\sum \limits_{n =1}^{\infty} a_n $converges, then $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} na_n = 0$

I think, we can say that $a_n = O(\frac{1}{n^\alpha}), \alpha > 1$, so for every member of the sequence $a_n < \frac{c}{n^\alpha}$ and then $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} na_n = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} n O(\frac{1}{n^\alpha}) = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} O(\frac{1}{n^{\alpha - 1}}) = 0$
But is this evaluation correct and how to prove it?

Comment: this is Abel's(or Pringsheim's) theorem: see http://mpec.sc.mahidol.ac.th/radok/physmath/mat11/chap8.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $n>0$,

let $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k$ and $v_n=na_n$.

as$(a_n)$ is positive and decreasing, we have

$$na_{2n}\leq (a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}+...a_{2n})$$

$$\implies 0\leq na_{2n}\leq (S_{2n}-S_n).$$

$\sum a_n $ converges $\implies (S_n)$ converges

$$\implies  \lim_{n\to+\infty} (S_{2n}-S_n)=0$$

$$\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}na_{2n}=0$$

$$\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}v_{2n}=0$$

by exactly the same approach, and using $\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n=0$ , we prove that $v_{2n+1} \to 0$ .